# IOTA and Tangle relation

Tags: tangle, iota-network

I used to think that IOTA is the cryptocurrency which uses the Tangle Direct Acyclic Graph. But today I spend some time on the [IOTA official](https://www.iota.org/) and there is no single appearance of the word "cryptocurrency". It is said that IOTA is a "Distributed Ledger Technology developed by the IOTA Foundation" which is "based on the revolutionary distributed ledger technology, the Tangle".
    So IOTA is a DLT based on a DLT ?

Comment: IOTA to Tangle is what Bitcoin to Blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

IOTA is the name of the project/network and also the name of the Token/Cryptocurrency. The Tangle, which is a DAG, is the data structure that is used by IOTA, same as the Blockchain is the data structure used by Bitcoin.  DLT is just a more generic term for the technology that most people refer to as "Blockchain" but for the case of the IOTA and a few other more recent projects, it is not correct because a DAG is not a blockchain.

I think what you meant to say is, IOTA is a DLT based on a DAG, this would be correct.